# how to use datastructures in windows form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I don't know if I am saying this clearly but I wanted to know how can we use data structures in windows form in c#, for example if I want to make a shopping store, in console app I can use linked lists to show list of items and when they are selected I put them in stack to make invoice later on.. 
but I want to know how to do all this in windows form, I click a button and it gives the linked list in form of buttons.
and one more thing if we can do the above mentioned thing can we also make linked list of buttons?
I know its a vague question but I want to know if we can do this.. if no then I stick to the console app.

Comment: First I don't know if this is the place to ask question like that. Second if you are forced to do with windows form application? because it seems more a Web application, although it is clear  that you can do this with a desktop application,oh and I think you should add some code to get idea of what do you want?.

Comment: The question as such is understandable, but more context is needed to see what exactly is to be done.

Comment: thank you for your time but i think i get the answer of what i was trying to ask. thank you anyways :)